# How to use XtraWaitForm before loading the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, devexpress, progress-bar

I've a Login form for authenticating users and the main form eventually loads after that. However, the main form (WinForm) takes a lot of time to load making users think that the form just froze. Hence, I would like kindly ask for your recommendation for the best way to handle the situation and how. Which one is better and easy: displaying a progress bar on the login form (till the main form finishes loading data) or XtraWaitForm before actually loading the main form? I'm using C# WinForm.

Comment: Primary opinion based? And what would you show in your XtraWaitFrom?

Comment: Probably, "Please wait till data loading is completed"